# Integrating differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this equation:

$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=-0.05y(t)-\sin(\pi/4)+F*\cos(0.7t)$$

My computation so far has been like this:

$$dy(t)=-0.05y(t)dt-\sin(\pi/4)dt+F*\cos(0.7t)dt$$

$$\int{dy(t)}=\int{-0.05y(t)dt}-\int{\sin(\pi/4)dt}+\int{F*\cos(0.7t)dt}$$
$$y(t)=\int{-0.05y(t)dt}-\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}+\int{F*\cos(0.7t)dt}$$

I'm stuck here. Don't know how to process with the integration. Any help with this?

Comment: Hi! This is a non homogeneous first order linear differential equation. There are some standard ways of solving this (see e.g. https://math24.net/linear-differential-equations-first-order.html) and a general formula too (I am posting that as soon as I find it).

Comment: I don’t know why I am not finding it easily. In any case, you can find the general formula here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_to_Linear_First_Order_ODE_with_Constant_Coefficients

Comment: What I forgot to say is that your equation is easy because has “constant coefficients”, i.e., there are no functions in the $t$ variable multiplying $y$ or its derivative. That’s why there is a fairly nice general formula

Answer (score 1):

I am just writing the answer I gave in the comments.
This is an ordinary differential equation, which is also linear non homogeneous, of the first order, and with constant coefficients.

There are a couple of smart ways to solve these equations, but the general formula for this kind of equation is given by the Duhamel’s principle: the solution to
$$y’(t)+ay(t)=g(t)\qquad\quad(1)$$
$$y(t_0)=y_0$$
is given by
$$y(t)=y_0e^{-a(t-t_0)}+\int_{t_0}^te^{-a(t-s)}g(s)ds.\qquad (2)$$

You can find a proof here
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_to_Linear_First_Order_ODE_with_Constant_Coefficients

So you have to apply this formula to your case, where $g(t)=-\sin(\pi/4)+F\cos(0.7t)$.

Comment: When applying the formula, you may also find this useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot! Just one thing I´m unsure about right now - you mentioned this equation: y'(t) + ay(t) = g(t). But what exactly is y'(t) in my case? Is it that dy(t)/dt? If so, how is that possible that it can be changed to that value like that?

Comment: To the first question: yes, it is. To the second question: it is not so immediate using just the properties of integrals, one needs to be a bit familiar with the theory of linear ODEs. To show that the expression (2) holds for $y(t)$, one just has to prove it. As I said, you can find the proof in the link above (Proof 1).

Comment: I assume you are now talking about (2). If you are instead talking about (1), this is simply a general way of rewriting your equation, where in your case $a=0.05$ and $g(t)=-\sin(\pi/4)+F\cos(0.7t)$.

Comment: The proof for (2) is not that hard actually. It’s just that you have to use the trick of multiply $y$ by $e^{at}$ and derivate, which looks a bit random, but it’s actually quite reasonable once you know the subject.

Comment: To be clear, with the calculations you wrote above you are not going anywhere. You have to use the formula (2) substituting $a$ and $g$ and solve the integral that you find on the right hand side of the equation to find the explicit solution.